# Почему один и тот-же код работает в функции и в классе по разному?

Tags: reactjs

Приветвую, у меня есть список checkBox-сов который создается из массива

```
 ProjectList.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <input  
                type="checkBox" 
                name={'check'+index}
                id={'check'+index}
                value={item.checked}
                checked={item.checked} 
                onChange={onChangeInput} />
              <label htmlFor={'check'+index}>{item.name}</label>
            </div>
          );
        })
```

вот событие которое срабатывает при клике по checkbox

```
const onChangeInput=({target})=>{
        let arr=ProjectList;
        for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            if (arr[i].name===target.labels[0].textContent)
            {
                arr[i].checked=target.checked;
                break;   
            }
            setProjectList(arr); 
    }
```

Как я понимаю состояние checkbox-а должно изменятся, но вот проблема, checkbox не меняется состояние при клике, точенее меняется это можно увидеть если поставить breakpoint в функции события но по после окончания функции checkbox возвращается в исходное состояние такая фигня у меня происходит в функции, а вот в классе точно такой-же код работает нормально.
Помогите разобраться плз.
Вот более понятный [пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-voice-neuo6?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо пересоздавать массив, как-то так:
`onChange={ev=>toggle(item)}`

```
const toggle = theItem => setProjectList(was => was.map(item => (
    item !== theItem ? item : {...item, checked: item.checked ? undefined : true }
)))
```

---

`item.checked ? undefined : true` возвращает `true` если `item.checked` `undefined`, и возвращает `undefined` если `item.checked` `true`.

`{...item, checked:` -- сконструировать новый объект, взяв всё из `item`, но заменив значение `checked`.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло, но вот я не очень понимаю вот эту часть`{...item, checked: item.checked ? undefined : true }`

Comment: добавил пояснение; раз помогло -- принимайте ответ галочкой.